# weights, selected features in adaboost classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there any keyword in `scikit-learn` for `AdaBoostClassifier` to return weights of the weak classifiers at each step?
IDK if the features are chosen randomly (For the weak Decision Trees that this classifiers provide for further learning processes) if it is so, how can we observe the chosen features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clf.estimator_weights_` would give the weights for each estimator in the ensemble.

[Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)

There is no sampling of random features in Adaboost classifier. There would be only sample weights based on the ensemble model error.

To know more about Adaboost technique, read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#adaboost).

May be you can look at the feature importance of individual decision trees. You can start by tweaking [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py#L247) function.

Comment: Glad that it helps!! Kindly review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have another related question,
If I implement my learning process by Random Forest, feature selection for random trees would be random, in this case?
If so how can I see the selected features?